# Como hacer que mi AlarmManager se active cada ocho días

Tags: android, android-studio

Quiero que mi alarma se active cada ocho dias como deberia de programarla ?

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                MyAlarmReceiver.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent
                = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(),
                id, myIntent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager1
                = (AlarmManager)getActivity().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hora);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuto);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, dia);

        long interval1 = Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH; //
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            alarmManager1.setAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        }else {
            alarmManager1.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Revisa la documentación relacionada a la clase [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms)

Para esta tarea puedes usar [setRepeating()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) que tiene la máxima exactitud o también [setInexactRepeating()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setInexactRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) que puede guardar la vida de tu batería pero no es tan exacta.

Un ejemplo usando [setRepeating()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)), para esto debes definir la cantidad en milisegundos a la cual tu alarma se repetirá, por lo tanto 8 días es igual a `691200000` milisegundos:

```
    alarmManager1.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 691200000,  pendingIntent);
```

de esta forma tu alarma se llamaría cada 8 días.